# FileNotFoundError, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, file-not-found

I'm  trying to open the files in my folder but it came out with this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TRAIN_00000.eml'
```

I had double check the file name and the directory/path written in the code but the problem still there.

Here's the chunk of code:

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\...\\TRAINING"
listing = os.listdir(path)


for em in listing:
    file = open(em, 'rb')
    e_content = file.read()
    file.close()

print (e_content)
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: `os.listdir()` only returns filenames, you must `os.path.join()` them with the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
for em in listing:
```

to:

```
for em in listing:
    em = os.path.join(path, em) # this is what you need to add
```

This should solve your problem.  The return from `os.listdir()` is a list of relative paths.  You need to make them absolute paths if you're not invoking the app in the *path* directory. Otherwise they are not found, as you've seen.